# Class with generic list of the inherited class type - multiinheritence

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have asked previously a question in this link
[Class with generic list of the inherited class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689363/class-with-generic-list-of-the-inherited-class-type)

now, in the following solution.
In This situation, How can i do a list (Descendents) of TvGuid ?

```
#region ParentItem
public class BaseHeaderFooterItem<T>
    where T:class 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string EnTitle { get; set; }
    public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public List<T> Descendants { get; set; }
}
#endregion

#region HeaderFooter
public class HeaderFooter : BaseHeaderFooterItem<Category>
{
}
#endregion

#region HeaderFooter
public class Category : BaseHeaderFooterItem<Show>
{
}
#endregion

#region Header
public class Show : HeaderFooter
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string MobileLink { get; set; }
    public string MobileLinkTarget { get; set; }
}
#endregion

#region TvGuid
public class TvGuid : Show
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }
    public int NoProgram { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate your BaseHeaderFooterItem class like this:

```
var baseHeaderFooterItem = new BaseHeaderFooterItem<TvGuid>();
baseHeaderFooterItem.Descendants = new List<TvGuid> { new TvGuid() };
```

So the Descendats' type will be List < TvGuid>. Alternatively you can create a class, which inherits from BaseHeaderFooterItem< TvGuid>. It will have the same List< TvGuid> property.